# How do I escape a colon in HAML

Tags: haml

Can any one tell me how to write this in HAML?

```
<td mc:edit = "headline">
```

The colon between the "mc" and the "edit" is what's screwing me up.

I tried:

```
%td{:mc\:edit => "headline"}

%td{:mc:\edit => "headline"}

%td{:mc:plain:edit => "headline"}

%td{:mc:escape:edit => "headline"}

%td(mc:edit = "headline")
```

They all return errors.

Comment: The last one should work, but without the spaces. `%td(mc:edit="headline")`

Answer (score 0):

Both, `%td{"mc:edit": "headline"}` or `%td(mc:edit="headline")` should work.

Using:

- haml (4.0.7)
- haml-rails (0.9.0)
- ruby-2.3.0
- rails (4.2.6)

Comment: Hello. Thank's for getting back to me on this. Unfortunately, neither of those solutions works.

Comment: Can you describe what tools/plugins/versions you use @belotte ?

Comment: @belotte can you post what error you are getting? Like I mentioned in my answer. Either of the versions I provided work. However, I am not using CodeKit and I don't know what error you are actually getting.